# chrome.identity API availability

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

Does anyone know when the chrome.identity API will make it to stable?

http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=233250 for progress. The API is unlikely to make Chrome 28 stable, but Chrome 29 is a possibility. Using the API in your in-development applications and filing bugs based on your usage are the kind of feedback the team needs to increase the chances of making stable sooner.

Comment: I see, thanks. I guess this is only for packaged apps, not extensions?

Comment: That's too bad :( It would be useful in extensions as well.

Comment: dear sowbug, can you please share the reference where it says that it is not available for extensions? On the docs page it doesnt mention it: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity.html

Comment: I guess extensions can use regular oauth to do it: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth.html